# Passing a generic function to operate on homogenous types

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14

Let's say I have a class composed of homogeneous types:

```
struct Homog {
    int a;
    double b;
    std::string c;
};
```

Here's a function which calculates the "element-wise min"<sup>1</sup> of two instances of this class:

```
Homog min(const Homog& l, const Homog& r) {
  return {
      std::min(l.a, r.a),
      std::min(l.b, r.b),
      std::min(l.c, r.c),
  };
}
```

Great.

Now I want to calculate the *max* instead of the *min*. The code is identical, but with `std::min` replaced with `std::max`. I wouldn't want to duplicate it, rather I'd like to have one generic "element-wise apply" method, and then the min and max just call that with the appropriate functor:

```
Homog apply(const Homog& l, const Homog& r, ?? op) {
  return {
      op(l.a, r.a),
      op(l.b, r.b),
      op(l.c, r.c),
  };
}

Homog min(const Homog& l, const Homog& r) {
    return apply(l, r, std::min);
}

Homog max(const Homog& l, const Homog& r) {
    return apply(l, r, std::max);
}
```

Of course, the above code doesn't work, because I don't know how to declare `op`. It is not a normal generic functor object, because it needs to work on different types.

Can I do what I want to, somehow passing something which says "call op for each member: don't worry, it will resolve to something for each type"?

---

Maybe using `min()` isn't the best name here, because it doesn't behave the same as `std::min` which always returns one of the two given objects: this method returns a new object which in general is not the same as either of the two inputs, but rather a mix of their member values.

Answer (score 2):

> Of course, the above code doesn't work, because I don't know how to declare op. It is not a normal generic functor object, because it needs to work on different types.

This problem is usually bypassed using a functional, with a template `operator()`.

Starting from C++14 (that introduce generic lambdas) simply as follows

```
template <typename F>
Homog apply(const Homog& l, const Homog& r, F const & op) {
  return {
      op(l.a, r.a),
      op(l.b, r.b),
      op(l.c, r.c),
  };
}

Homog min(const Homog& l, const Homog& r) {
    return apply(l, r, [](auto const & a, auto const & b){ return std::min(a, b); });
}
```

Comment: Ah yes, generic lambda is the key. Any equivalent solution for C++11?

Comment: @BeeOnRope - lambdas (and generic lambdas) are only syntactic sugar for a class with an `operator()` in it (a potentially template one, starting from C++14). So, to "simulate" a generic lambda in C++11 (but also C++98, if I'm not wrong) you have to do the hard work and explicitly define the class with a template `operator()` inside it.

Comment: thanks, it makes sense. Is too bad because it just moves some of the work from re-implementing the apply method to "wrapping" each functor like thing with a generic version to do the indirection. I wonder if a template template solution is possible?

Comment: @BeeOnRope - I don't think a template-template can be useful in this case: you have to do with template functions, not with template struct/classes. But maybe I'm wrong and someone more skilled can disprove me.

Comment: Thanks, this seems like the solution I'll use. I've asked [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55987832/149138) about defining once the functor objects wrapping the various methods I call about, maybe I can reduce the boilerplate there.