# Reducing boilerplate when creating functor objects for std template functions

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, boilerplate

As a solution to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55987078/149138) it seems useful to create "generic functor objects" which wrap various standard (and perhaps user-defined) template functions in a functor object.

These are sometimes more useful than the corresponding template functions because the specific type of the function is "bound late" when passed as a functor object: only at the call site within the callee, rather than at the caller. For example, you cannot pass `std::min` as a functor object, you must pass a instantiation like `std::min<int>` which means the callee cannot operate on a variety of homogenous types.

On the other hand, you can pass `min_functor` as shown below and the right instantiation of `min` will be chosen at each call side in the callee.

```
struct min_functor {
    template <typename T>
    const T& operator()(const T& l, const T& r) const { return std::min(l,r); }
};
```

Finally, the question: if I want to define several of these for various binary operations like `max` and so on, is there some way to do it without copying the boilerplate above, other than macros<sup>1</sup>?

---

<sup>1</sup> It seems like macros would work pretty well here, but I can't bear to face the scorn of the powerful anti-macro lobby.

Comment: C++14 lambdas do this pretty well: `auto min_functor = [](const auto& l, const auto& r) { return std::min(l, r); };`

Comment: @BrianRodriguez - it looks almost identical in terms of boilerplate? A few characters here, a few characters there, but all the key elements are the same. It is not able to be used in all the same places as `min_functor` either, because it has no type (you'd use yours like `min_functor` but the original one like `min_functor{}` when you wanted an instance) - but I don't know if that's a pro or or. Doens't work in C++11 which is a big downside.

Comment: @beeo C++11 is 8 years ago and gaining.  It is a big downside to be restricted to using C++11; it is not a big downside to have code that won't work in C++11.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont - maybe in your world, in my world it's a big downside. There are many real world scenarios where you'd be _lucky_ even to use C++11! In any case, the mentioned solution seems to have almost zero upside compared to the version shown in the question to compensate for any downside? It doens't reduce the boilerplate really: you have to repeat all the same things. In any case, I'm not interested in a debate about C++11 usefulness: I tagged this question `c++11` so solutions that work there are preferred.

Comment: Just you macro.  A macro that handles boilerplate is fine.  Just give it a nice name like functorize.  Macros are evil when you use them instead of the proper techniques like templates.

Answer (score 2):

**No**, because you can’t name a function template without **immediate** context that identifies a specialization of it.  (Consider that template template arguments must be class or alias templates.)  There are several caveats, however:

1. Several syntaxes to do so [have been **proposed**](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2018/p1170r0.html).
2. A function template can be passed as an argument for a parameter that is a **function pointer** (at the cost of no state and probably no inlining).
3. Some modern designs use [function **objects**](http://eel.is/c++draft/algorithms#requirements-2) directly, although this is really just including the same boilerplate ahead of time.